# Interaction With WebPage VBA

Tags: html, excel, web, vba

I'm creating a code that allows me to open a specific site and  enter value in element with the name `searchByTagName=searchByTRSMP` and then Type search to load the new window

But the problem that button search doesn't have a TagName or IdName only this

```
<td width="13%" align="center" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1">
   <input name="" onclick="Javascript:document.forms[0].submit();return false;" type="image" srx="/cmh/cmh/xxxxxx" border="0"></input>
```

Anyone Can Light me on pressing that button with only those conditions

this Mycode :

```
Sub ToComb()
 Dim ie  As Object
 Dim itm As IHTMLElement

 Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 ie.Visible = True
 ie.navigate "http://XXXX- 
 XXXX.eu.airbus.XXXXXp:XXXXX/cmh/consultation/preSearchTRSTDMAS.do? 
 clearBackList=true&CMH_NO_STORING_fromMenu=true"
  While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

  Set itm = ie.document.getElementsByName("searchByTRSMP")(0)
   If Not itm Is Nothing Then itm.Value = "k20734"
   Set Doc = ie.document


    Set tags = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("")
    For Each tagx In tags
     If tagx.Value = "Next" Then
     tagx.Click
    Exit For
   End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetElementsByTagname` mean search for an element by the type of an HTML element (such as, `div`, `p` or in your example - `input`).

You can get all your inputs tags (elements), iterate them and identify the required input, based on it's (for example) `srx` attribute:

```
Set tags = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagname("Input")

For Each tagx In tags
    If tagx.src= "/cmh/cmh/xxxxxx" Then
        tagx.Click
    End If
Next
```

In addition, the final `src` of the `input` might changed from the actual code, because you use a relative path. Check the actual `src` with a MsgBox:

```
For Each tagx In tags 
    MsgBox tagx.src
```

I assume it will be different, such as prefix of `http` and so on:

```
If tagx.src = "http://xxxx 
   xxxx.eu.airbus.xxx:xxxx/cxxx/xxx/image/button_search.gif" Then
```

Comment: the button got this 'src="/cmh/cmh/image/button_search.gif"' so i thing it is tagx.src .. i tested it but nothing as result

Comment: @POLOSTutorials is the condition evaluates to `true` and only the `click` doesn't work ? what exactly happening ? debug the code and check that `if tagx.src = "/cmh/cmh/image/button_search.gif"` evaluates to true. you can also check what is the actual value of `tagx.src`. Let me know.

Comment: the page is loaded but nothing happens the click doesn't work  :'(

Comment: Under the line of tagx.Click i put an msgbox to see if that part is working or not but nothing as result the msg doesn't display... the problem starts from here  For each tagx in Tags ....

Comment: @POLOSTutorials can you check what items `tags` contain

Comment: tags = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagname("input") thats what u mean ???  sorry i'm a little bit newbish because there is no tags in the html code of that page

Comment: @POLOSTutorials yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167260/discussion-between-alon-adler-and-polos-tutorials).